# TCP connection capable of sending http requests

Tags: java, http, tcp

I am trying to build a simple web server (TCP) capable of receiving, treating and responding http requests. I have already stablished a TCP connection between Client and Server,  problem is, although I've tried, I haven't managed to do the http request. 
These are the Client and Server codes in Java:

**CLIENT CLASS:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import java.net.Socket;

import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class SocketCliente {

private String hostname;
private int porta;
Socket socketCliente;

public SocketCliente(String hostname, int porta){
    this.hostname = hostname;
    this.porta = porta;
}

public void connect() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
    System.out.println("Tentando se conectar com "+hostname+":"+porta);
    socketCliente = new Socket(hostname,porta);
    System.out.println("A conexão foi realizada");
}

public void readResponse() throws IOException{
    String userInput;
    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketCliente.getInputStream()));

    System.out.println("Responsta do servidor:");
    while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(userInput);
    }
}

public static void main(String arg[]){
    //Creating a SocketClient object
    SocketCliente client = new SocketCliente ("localhost",30000);
    try {
        //trying to establish connection to the server
        client.connect();
        //if successful, read response from server
        client.readResponse();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("A conexão não pode ser estabelecida.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Conexão não estabelecida, pois o servidor pode ter problemas."+e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

**SERVER CLASS**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.net.ServerSocket;

import java.net.Socket;


public class SocketServidor {

private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private int porta;

public SocketServidor(int porta) {
    this.porta = porta;
}

public void start() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Começando o servidor na porta:" + porta);
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(porta);

    //Listen for clients. Block till one connects

    System.out.println("Esperando o cliente");
    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

    //A client has connected to this server. Send welcome message
    sendMensagemDeBoasVindas(client);
}

private void sendMensagemDeBoasVindas(Socket cliente) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(cliente.getOutputStream()));
    writer.write("A sua conexão com o SocketServidor foi feita");
    writer.flush();
}

/**
* Creates a SocketServer object and starts the server.
*
* @param 
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Setting a default port number.
    int portNumber = 30000;

    try {
        // initializing the Socket Server
        SocketServidor socketServer = new SocketServidor(portNumber);
        socketServer.start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I truly have no idea of how I can make a http request. I've tried creating a http class, I've tried sending the request from the existing Client class, but nothing has worked so far. And all the google searches haven't helped.

A friend, who's also trying to do it, told me that you need to send the request from the Client class to the Server class after they've already made the connection. How do I do this?

Please, can you help me?

@Robin-Green
**CLIENT CLASS:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class SocketCliente {
private String hostname;
private int porta;
Socket socketCliente;

public SocketCliente(String hostname, int porta){
    this.hostname = hostname;
    this.porta = porta;
}

public void connect() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
    System.out.println("Tentando se conectar com "+hostname+":"+porta);
    socketCliente = new Socket(hostname,porta);
    System.out.println("A conexão foi realizada");
}

public void readResponse() throws IOException{
    String userInput;
    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketCliente.getInputStream()));

    System.out.println("Responsta do servidor:");
    while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(userInput);
    }
}
public void HTTPCliente() throws Exception{
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socketCliente.getOutputStream()));
    System.out.println("GET / HTTP/1.1");
    System.out.println("User-Agent: test/1.0");
    System.out.println("Host: localhost");
    System.out.println("Accept: */*");
}

public static void main(String arg[]){
    //Creating a SocketClient object
    SocketCliente client = new SocketCliente ("localhost",30000);
    try {
        //trying to establish connection to the server
        client.connect();
        //if successful, read response from server
        client.readResponse();
        try {
            //se http obtiver sucesso
            client.HTTPCliente();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SocketCliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("A conexão não pode ser estabelecida.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Conexão não pode ser feita por problemas no servidor."+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please show us the code where you tried to send the request from the client.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have it here with me right now: I, unfortunately, forgot it at the school lab computer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send something like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: test/1.0
Host: localhost
Accept: */*
```

so maybe:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socketCliente.getOutputStream()));
out.println("GET / HTTP/1.1");
out.println("User-Agent: test/1.0");
out.println("Host: localhost");
out.println("Accept: */*");
```

but by the way, this is the low-level, more complicated way. It's easier to do it with a high-level API. But maybe that is not allowed in this homework assignment, I don't know.

Comment: Ok. I tried this at my Client class, however nothing happened: it didn't print or give error. So, what does the server do in this process? How do I make him get this request? P.S.: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: HTTP is a protocol that allows a request to target itself at a particular resource. Since you only have one resource, you could ignore the data in the request, but this is kind of cheating. So really you should parse the first line of the request, extract the URL from it (/ in this case), and if it is what you expect, produce an appropriate HTTP response. As for why nothing happened, I don't know - post your updated code please.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've updated the code. Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: sorry, that's not enough detail. Please post the actual code when you are back at the computer.

Comment: The code I have with me right now or the one that I left at school? Because the one I have at school I'll only be able to get on Wednesday...

Comment: whatever, the full code you have actually tried to run, without any missing bits